# Yii URL Management

Tags: url, yii

I have a usecase which requires a specific usage of urls. I want the users to have their own page and the url should be in such a way it is easy for them to remember their page.

I was thinking of making the url DOMAIN.COM/USERNAME

How can I achieve this? I probably should make an url manager? How can I make it in such way the 'normal' controllers would still work?

Comment: How could the 'normal' controllers still work, if you can no longer use the URL to access them? How do you intend to access them?

Comment: The idea was to make it first search if the USERNAME part is a username, or actually an existing controller. If it is an existing controller => Forward it to the controller, else render the user page

Comment: What about naming conflicts between the user and the controller? Or do you simply disallow the user to select a name like 'site', if you have a SiteController?

Comment: Yep, that would be the idea yes :-). And with the solution soju provided, if a user has the name site the user his page won't work since the site URL rule would be prior :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you should read this : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url

Yii URL management is quite handy, e.g. :

```
'urlManager'=>array(
  .....
  'rules'=>array(
    .....
    // AFTER other rules
    '<userName:.+>' => 'user/view',
```

Yii will use the first matching rule, so you have to define rules for other controllers before this one.

And in your controller :

```
public function actionView($userName)
{
  // do what you want
}
```