# Yii url manger with url parameter

Tags: url, yii, yii-url-manager

What I'm trying to do is when users signup they have a custom url to their own page, like so:

```
www.mysite.com/username
```

How do I set the url manager in Yii to achieve this? I know you use this somehow.

```
<url:[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+>
```

Also with controller and action with that url:

```
www.mysite.com/username/controller/action
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii URL Management](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15578398/yii-url-management)

Answer (score 0):

Put this **AFTER ALL** the other rules:

```
// one content type can have special urls
'<username>' => 'user/view',
```

Assuming your controller's function params are:

```
    public function actionView($username) {

        // code to get user by username (instead of by $id)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do what ever you want after reading this:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/fr/topics.url#using-custom-url-rule-classes

i advice to read all article! it's helpfull!